# API Yandex Map Нет зума при клике на кластер

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

почему-то не происходит зума при клике на некоторые кластера при некотором зуме карты. [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/02tmLwo5/6/), кликаем на кластер с 13 точками и скролл к месту есть, а зума нет. Хотелось бы раскрывать кластер. Игрался с gridSize, если ставить по умолчанию - ситуация улучшается, но хочется видеть поменьше кластеров, поэтому gridSize и увеличиваю.

```
    ymaps.ready(function() {
      var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
          center: [55.809343, 37.628505],
          zoom: 14,
          controls: [],
        }, {}),
        clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
          gridSize: 128,
          groupByCoordinates: false,
        }),
    points = [
      [55.811928, 37.658643],
      [55.810192, 37.638701],
      [55.811771, 37.639339],
      [55.812666, 37.636859],
      [55.808867, 37.653783],
      [55.807501, 37.631559],
      [55.806069, 37.635512],
      [55.806004, 37.644297],
      [55.806631, 37.640767],
      [55.809069, 37.634991],
      [55.810091, 37.640264],
      [55.80744, 37.632493],
      [55.810602, 37.632098],
      [55.805943, 37.637847],
      [55.809231, 37.636392],
      [55.806019, 37.630409],
      [55.807466, 37.614734],
      [55.80737, 37.611446],
      [55.807972, 37.640758],
      [55.810486, 37.619162],
      [55.806798, 37.638961],
      [55.810081, 37.632745],
      [55.810688, 37.63676],
      [55.808179, 37.641998],
      [55.809596, 37.634434],
      [55.810086, 37.651053],
      [55.809904, 37.635081],
      [55.81129, 37.633958],
      [55.812418, 37.654709],
      [55.807911, 37.612362],
      [55.806439, 37.643974],
      [55.811452, 37.632799]
    ];
  geoObjects = [];

  /**
   * Данные передаются вторым параметром в конструктор метки, опции - третьим.
   * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Placemark.xml#constructor-summary
   */
  for (var i = 0, len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
    geoObjects[i] = new ymaps.Placemark(points[i], {}, {});
  }

  /**
   * Можно менять опции кластеризатора после создания.
   */
  // clusterer.options.set({
  //     gridSize: 80,
  //     clusterDisableClickZoom: true
  // });

  /**
   * В кластеризатор можно добавить javascript-массив меток (не геоколлекцию) или одну метку.
   * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Clusterer.xml#add
   */
  clusterer.add(geoObjects);
  myMap.geoObjects.add(clusterer);

  /**
   * Спозиционируем карту так, чтобы на ней были видны все объекты.
   */
  myMap.container.fitToViewport();
  // myMap.setBounds(clusterer.getBounds(), {
  //     checkZoomRange: true
  // });
  myMap.controls.add(new ymaps.control.ZoomControl({
    options: {
      position: {
        "left": 10,
        "top": 30
      }
    },
  }));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

При клике на кластер апи получает границы области которая охватывает все метки, которые есть в кластере. Затем пытается выставить эту область карте, чтобы все метки остались в видимой области карты. Если эта область не помещается на карту на следующем зуме, то зума происходить не будет.

Вы можете обрабатывать клик по кластеру и изменять зум самостоятельно.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. полазил немного поглубже, нашел, что clusterPlacemark использует map.setBounds для этого, а разве промис от setBounds не должен reject в таком случае кинуть, что не смог такие bounds поставить? чтобы потом вручную изменить зум?
или можно как то иначе определить,что по дефолту зума не будет и надо добавить его вручную?

Comment: вы предалагаете делать что-то вроде?
```clusterPlacemark.events.add('click', (event) => {
          const needZoom = ymaps.util.bounds.containsBounds(myMap.getBounds(), clusterPlacemark.getBounds());
          if (needZoom) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            const center = ymaps.util.bounds.getCenter(clusterPlacemark.getBounds());
            myMap.setCenter(center, myMap.getZoom() + 1);
          }
        }, clusterPlacemark, 200);```
кстати, нет ли метода, чтобы узнать до какого зума надо зумить, чтобы кластер распался хотя бы на 2 метки?

Comment: "reject в таком случае кинуть, что не смог такие bounds поставить?" Дык он же смог поставить, он ставит тот баундс что охватывает метки. Опишите конкретно какого поведения хотите добиться. Сейчас как то туманно выглядит.